# Convert files Lead to Custom object

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder, lead-conversion, field-mapping

I have files (ContentDocument) attached to a Lead on conversion I map the Lead to a custom object trough process builder. Is there a Id or field I can use to map the files attached to the custom object or do I need to write a trigger?

Comment: You have to use trigger and create contentDocumentLinks for the new record

Comment: @PranayJaiswal  Ok so there is no way to get the ContentDocumentId? If so please update your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via trigger route, You can Query on ContentDocumentLink object to get all the files related to the any particular record. **LinkedEntityId** on ContentDocumentLink tells ID of the linked object. Can include Chatter users, groups, records (any that support Chatter feed tracking including custom objects), and Salesforce CRM Content libraries.

A sample query which you can modify as per the requirement:-

```
SELECT ContentDocumentId  FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE  LinkedEntityId = '0D5000000089123'
```

> For getting the ContentDocumentID, You can store the ContentDocumentID
>   in set variable and query on ContentDocument object. Link it with the
>   new Custom Object record using insertion of ContentdocumentLink
>   object.